# I want to use the amp-youtube tag in ampstory

Tags: amp-html, amp-youtube, amp-story

I want to use the amp-youtube tag in ampstory!! but not working...

On page 1, 2 pages are automatically executed with the autoplay option. And it can not be executed from page 3. Despite the same autoplay option. And it runs at the same time as Page 2 Page 1.

Comment: It would be great if you shared the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently valid to use `amp-youtube` within `amp-story`.  There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15847) tracking the implementation of this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback